# SQL Multiple IINNER JOIN & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

the three tables I am trying to query are:

**DB Structure:**

`roles_permissions: id, role_id, permission_id`

`user_roles: id, name, user_id`

`permissions: id, name`

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT ur.name AS role_name,perm.name AS perm_name FROM user_roles AS ur
    INNER JOIN roles_permissions as p
    ON ur.id=p.role_id
    INNER JOIN permissions AS perm
    ON p.permission_id = perm.id
    WHERE ur.user_id='$account_id'
```

**Result from above query**

```
    array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Owner"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(6) "Editor"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(14) "create project"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Owner"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(6) "Editor"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(14) "create project"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Owner"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(6) "Editor"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Owner"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["role_name"]=>
    string(6) "Editor"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(14) "create project"
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is select all `user_roles` assigned to a specific user_id, then get the permission ids assigned to that role from `roles_permissions`, then get the names of each permission from the `permissions` table. I would like to group by `user_roles.name`

so the resulting array would be

```
    array(3) {
  ["Owner"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "create project"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
  ["Editor"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }
   ["Admin"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "view project"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "create project"
    ["perm_name"]=>
    string(12) "edit project"
  }

}
```

So if anyone can help that would be great, also looking to learn from this so if you could explain it for me that would be awesome.

Thanks

SQL FIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7954/1

Comment: Please provide sample data for your tables.

Comment: Could you use an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: What version of mySQL?  There are two basic ways to get this sort of results set - use a DB function to return an array/delimited list, or construct it on the application side.

Comment: my server is running version 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't directly solve your problem, but your schema has a number of issues.  Chief among them is that the tuple `(role_id, permission_id)` in `roles_permissions` isn't unique.  Here's how I'd restructure things:

```
role
==========
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar

user_role
===========
role_id  -- fk to role.id
user_id  -- fk to user.id (not listed here, but you obviously have one)

permission
===========
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar

role_permission
===================
role_id  -- fk to role.id
permission_id  -- fk to permission.id
```

(note that if you're attempting to do permission groups or role hierarchies this gets more complicated)

[The modified example fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf35/9) showing the setup, with sample data.

Comment: It didnt solve my problem but I ended up rewriting a lot of my code based on your schema, I can see it saving me a lot of time in the long run

Answer (score 1):

Your test data is wrong i.e. user_role.id = 1 (name = owner, user_id = 1) in table role_permission for role_id = 1 has only permission_id = 1 (i.e. view) ;

Check your updated sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41b7b/2

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structure it's hard to test this out but have you tried just adding:

```
group by ur.name, perm.name
order by ur.name
```

at after the where clause?

Comment: The problem here won't be solved by a `GROUP BY`, although an `ORDER BY` would help to put the data in the format he wants...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yes, order by brings the result very close to what im looking for but it doesnt quite match the example in my post. Im starting to wonder if this is possible at all.